# How to compare only yyyy-MM from a date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a `datetime` field in my table with dates like

```
2012-11-29 00:00:00.000
```

I want to make a `where` in my query and filter only dates like `2012-11`

I tried to make `left(datefield,7) = for example '2012-10'` but it doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: Compare against what? Another date? varchar?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: compare against a string, sql server

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

In `sql-server`

```
...where LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, datefield,112),6)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` functions to compare:

```
YEAR(fielddate) = 2012 AND MONTH(fielddate) = 10
```

or

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, fielddate, 112), 1, 6) = '201210'
```

or

```
CONVERT(varchar, fielddate, 112) Like '201210%'
```

> **Note :**
>   You can use `REPLACE('2012-10', '-', '')` to have `201210`.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help-- in SQL SERVER

```
where  convert(varchar,datepart(yyyy,getdate()))+'-'+convert(varchar,datepart(MM,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons it's not good to compare a date as string. So better try a range approach like:

```
where date BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-12-01'
```

so the task is build the ending and starting of the month in the programming language you are using

Comment: `BETWEEN '2012-11-01' AND '2012-12-01'` is `>= '2012-11-01' AND <= '2012-12-01'` it should be `>= '2012-11-01' AND < '2012-12-01'` ;).

Comment: yeah you are totally right. mixed up some sql dialects :)